# categories not reflecting on front end side on magento ver1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

i have purchased sm market theme for magento.
i have created a category.
here is what i have checked and ensured 
stock-in stock, quantity>0,isActive-Yes,showinNavigation-Yes,Visibility - search,category,status-enabled etc

problem - category in not displaying on fronend

Answer (score 0):

Check the option in category:
include in navigation menu and set it to yes/true/checked whatever it is